# Audio output on Chrome when using WebRTC

Tags: google-chrome, audio, webrtc

I am using Chrome Version 62.0.3202.75 on macOS 10.12.6.

As of today, any WebRTC audio is now fed to my headset speaker. It would always use whatever the default speaker was set to in Mac sound setting (set to iMac speakers). This is the same in my app and all other WebRTC apps I have tried from.

YouTube and other sounds from the browser still come through the computer speakers as expected.

I can't find anyway to change this apart from unplugging headset and I can find no documentation / release notes on it. It does not happen in other browsers.

Any ideas?

Comment: can it be changed on https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/ ? If yes complaining in the M62 release note thread on the discuss-webrtc list is in order.

Comment: Yes it can be changed on here. Is the complaint due to the fact that I should of had to enable Experimental Features or set --enable-blink-features=EnumerateDevices,AudioOutputDevices for this to work, but I didn't have to at all, i.e it has been released early?

Comment: both features have been enabled by default for more than a year. So this is more likely a regression.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry to be a bit thick, what would the regression/issue be then? The fact that it should pick my system audio output by default?

Comment: This does seem to be a regression issue as I do not have the problem on v61

Comment: exactly. And when there is a regression you are entitled to complain ;-)